# Tomcat 9/Eclipse 2020-12: HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

[![404][1]][1]

Picture shows error message and path it tries to execute. I have tried everyhing, but it will not execute. Anyne got an idea on what is wrong?...

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to execute this, and why is your web context in the URL twice?

Comment: Good question, I do not know why it is twice in there. I started a new project just to see, and now the error still is there (Project name is Valg and servelt/class name is Valg (too)), Took a screenshot of todays error...

Comment: What URI mapping are you using for your servlet? And how are you triggering these browsers to open?

Comment: Eclipses internal browser.

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Valg</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Valg</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Valg</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/valg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: And how are you getting a browser opening with this incorrect URL?

Comment: I am running the code from inside Eclipse, Ctrl-F11.

Comment: The correct URI would just combine your context root and the url-pattern value, and it would be case sensitive. I have no idea how it's opening to the two, different, URLs in your screenshots.

Comment: The second one is the going one. I reinstalled Eclips an just named it Valg for now. I'll delete the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Valg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ecs.valg.Valg</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Valg</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Valg/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Had to make the source files member of package :-/